# Can I use Dynamics CRM as a Shopping Website?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I have couple of questions related to the usage of Dynamics CRM:

1. Can it be used like a shopping website?
2. If I am using it like a Shopping website, will I have to buy a license for every registered user on my website?
3. Or do you think Dynamics CRM is not made to behave like a shopping website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Absolutely, with some development, Microsoft CRM can be used as the database for your shopping website.  You can use the built-in product catalog and price lists for your sales.  Microsoft CRM has entities built into it for lead -> opportunity -> quote -> order -> invoice and you can repurpose any or all of these to work as you need them.

2) Typically the users of your shopping website will coincide with CRM contacts, which is great because you don't need user licenses for them.  You will have to license each end user of the system but this is limited to employees of your business.  In some scenarios you may need to purchase one external connector license which licenses you to expose data through a web site or other medium - see this blog for more details http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mscrmfreak/archive/2007/06/01/repeat-external-connector-license.aspx.  You will need to develop the website shopping site front end and integrate it with Microsoft CRM using the Dynamics CRM SDK.

3) Building portals to Microsoft CRM is actually a very common request.  A shopping website is a type of portal, another type would be a customer self service website.  Both can utilize the Microsoft CRM database to get 60% of the way, and then integrate with the website.

Comment: Thanks Cole. Can you give me more links regarding this scenario.

Comment: Microsoft offered a accelerators which got portals up to speed quickly in 4.0.  These accelerators can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681557.aspx.  Unfortunately, since Microsoft CRM just transitioned to 2011, there are not many of these pre-built solutions out yet.  Microsoft has a 2011 customer portal built out but it appears to have mixed reviews - http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-us/applications/customer-portal-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-12884910826/company.

Comment: The Microsoft CRM SDK is a great place for you to start if you have development experience.  It has excellent examples for integrating a website with the Microsoft CRM database.  The SDK for 2011 can be found here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24004.  If you do not have access to development resources you can work with a Microsoft Dynamics partner to develop a portal for you.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use Microsoft Dynamics CRM to build a shopping website, I wouldn't recommend it. A CRM and a framework for ecommerce are two different beasts. Look for a product that is specifically created for a shopping website, rather than attempting to manipulate Dynamics CRM.